# MongoDB Java - UpdateMany() with both an $inc operator and $concat aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-update

***JavaVersion: 11 ---
MongoDB-driver: 4.6.1***

I'm wondering if it is possible to implement a bulk update method that would increment the document version through the **$inc operator** while simultaneously making it possible to concatenate a string to a field value through **$concat aggregation**.

I've tried some workarounds, but I cannot manage the whole thing to work, in particular:

1. **Combining all the operators** in a single Bson with Updates::combine -> $concat and $inc works independently, but combining both of them I get this error: *"A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."*
2. Passing a **List of Bson** to "updateMany() ->  I get no error, but $concat does not work as expected, in the DB I have something like:

   ```
   "field1": {"$concat": ["$field1", "_OK"]},
   ```

In order to make $concat work I use this (according to the documentation):

```
        Updates.set(new Document("$concat", Arrays.asList(
            new BsonString(String.format("$%s", key)),
            new BsonString(value))));
```

While for $inc I'm using the Updetes.inc() method.

Comment: You cannot combine the update operators with pipeline operators - in an update query. For the `$inc` operation use `$add` aggregation operator (add 1 to current value).

Comment: Thank you now it works! There was also some other problem in the structure but nothing too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

As pointed out by ***prasad_*** in the comments, you can't combine update operators with pipeline ones. To solve the issue, I've used a List of BSON using $add aggregation instead of the $inc operator.

An implementation idea for the $add operator.

```
Updates.set(key, new Document("$add", Arrays.asList(
                new BsonString(key),
                value)));
```